# Selecting the first-level text element '.text()' without selecting child elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html

```
<label>
outer
<span>inner</span>
</label>
```

I want to replace the 'outer' value, leaving the span with its 'inner' text intact. Using

```
$('label').text('new outer');
```

replaces the entire content of the label (along with the span). Is there a nifty way to only select the text block 'outer' without adding extra spans or doing advanced stuff like storing the value of the label's inner span and then reapplying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a nifty way to only select the text block 'outer' without adding extra spans or doing advanced stuff like storing the value of the label's inner span and then reapplying it?

Not really.

You *could* use a regular expression to replace everything before `<span>`, but it would be a clunky regex, and while it would work for some cases, it would break if you had any other markup in there, especially if you had another element wrapping the `<span>`.

My suggestion would be to simply put another span in there. If you know you're going to be manipulating that block of code, then give it an element in the DOM. That's the best way to make it easy to get at, and it gets you away from doing silly stuff like rebuilding the whole structure just because you wanted to change a single word.

Comment: Thanks - this is actually what i ended up doing.

Answer (score 7):

This will update just the text of the first [`Text` node](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772) in the element, without disturbing the `span` (or any subsequent `Text` nodes):

```
$("label").contents().each(function() {
  // Within this iterator function, jQuery sets `this` to be
  // each child node (including Text nodes, not just Elements)
  if (this.nodeType === 3) { // 3 = text node
      this.nodeValue = "updated ";
      return false;
  }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/iyulen) | [source](http://jsbin.com/iyulen/edit)

And of course, you can refine that. The `Text` node's current text is available (of course) from `node.nodeValue`, so if you wanted to just modify that (perhaps replacing only certain parts of it), you can do that; or if you wanted to modify the first one that matched a given pattern, etc.

Comment: I like the answer, even if i decided not to go that way :)

Comment: Thank you for providing this answer, it was really helpful in the case where i had a label that included text and child elements. The jQuery text() method was replacing everything.