# Get Text from h3 element without getting text from child elements of h3

Tags: jquery

Here is what I want:

```
<h3 class="ExpressCheckoutTitle">
            <a onclick="" href="#" class="ChangeLink">Modify »</a>
            Step 4: Order Confirmation
  </h3>
```

I want to get just the text "Step 4: Order Confirmation"

`$('h3.ExpressCheckoutTitle').text()`  gives me the text from the `<a>` element as well like this: "Modify >> Step 4: Order Confirmation"

How do I do this in jquery?

Comment: We **just** had this question last week, but I'm *(mumbled)* if I can find it...

Comment: Ran across the question I mentioned above by coincidence: [Selecting the first-level text element '.text()' without selecting child elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932926/selecting-the-first-level-text-element-text-without-selecting-child-element)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `contents()` to access the textNodes directly. Try this:

```
var text = $("h3").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/N2rR4/)

Comment: I keep forgetting that `contents` will include text nodes.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `.contents` and filter by `nodeType == 3`. see

```
var h3Text = $('h3.ExpressCheckoutTitle').contents().filter(function() {
   return this.nodeType == 3
}).text();

alert($.trim(h3Text));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Sn4B/2/)

**Edit:** Updated after using $.trim to remove the trailing spaces.. and also used filter properly